# Linking V8 Statically

Tags: c++, visual-c++, v8, embedded-v8

I have a project that works perfectly with V8 dynamically, but I want to embed it statically.  I can successfully compile V8 as static, but when I included the resulting libs in my C++ project (which I also changed to static linking), I get errors like this:

```
Error   12  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall v8::HandleScope::HandleScope(class v8::Isolate *)" (__imp_??0HandleScope@v8@@QAE@PAVIsolate@1@@Z)
```

I have many other errors as well.  I've seen some posts mention a v8.lib, but it is not present.  There is, however, a v8.obj file.

Any insight would be most welcome, thanks.

Comment: `__declspec(dllimport)` this means the header you are using for v8::HandleScope is for use with a dll or at least the defines are set to import.

Comment: Ah, ok.  It's been years since I did any major C++ development.  I'm so rusty now, lol.  Makes sense, that my be the light I needed. ;)  I'll check some things ...

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem.  It's actually clearly stated at the top of the v8.h file:

```
// Setup for Windows DLL export/import. When building the V8 DLL the
// BUILDING_V8_SHARED needs to be defined. When building a program which uses
// the V8 DLL USING_V8_SHARED needs to be defined. When either building the V8
// static library or building a program which uses the V8 static library neither
// BUILDING_V8_SHARED nor USING_V8_SHARED should be defined.
```

I still had 'USING_V8_SHARED' defined.  Thanks to @drescherjm for pointing me in the right direction. ;)